# nextjs antd5 refresh break css first time

Tags: next.js, antd

nextjs antd5 refresh break css first time

I create create-next-app@latest --typescript and install antd

but refresh page (F5) first time break css ( not load? )

this is problem cssinjs?

Error view gif

[image: 1]

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@ant-design/icons": "^4.8.0",
        "@next/font": "13.1.0",
        "@types/node": "18.11.17",
        "@types/react": "18.0.26",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
        "antd": "^5.0.2",
        "eslint": "8.30.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.1.0",
        "next": "13.1.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "4.9.4"
    }
```

`

and I tired antd version downgrade 4.x.x then this problem is not detect

but antd 5.x.x is this problem detected

nextjs version is 12.x.x , 13.x.x no problem